# Storing class instance in new variable causes weird behavior (Arduino Serial)

Tags: c++, object, arduino, instance-variables

I was just trying to create a new variable to store the Serial object in that the Arduino provides by default.

Now here is what I don't understand:

Why is the output of this first code only `334`

```
HardwareSerial SerialB = Serial;

void setup() {
  SerialB.begin(115200);
  SerialB.print(0x33, HEX);
  SerialB.print(0x44, HEX);
  SerialB.print(0x55, HEX);
}

void loop() {
  //do nothing
}
```

And the output of this second code is `334455`

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.print(0x33, HEX);
  Serial.print(0x44, HEX);
  Serial.print(0x55, HEX);
}

void loop() {
  //do nothing
}
```

Why does the first code stop while printing the second byte? What am I misunderstanding here? Shouldn't both codes result in the same output?

Comment: The [following thread](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=68229.0) describes that it makes no sense to create a new instance of `HardwareSerial` (_"In any case, you should not be trying to CREATE a new instance of the HardwareSerial class"_). Are you perhaps looking to create a pointer to the existing `Serial` instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As dfri said, you were making another HardwareSerial instance, with disastrous results.

Just use a *reference*.  It's like a pointer, except the dot notation is used instead of having to use the arrow notation:

```
HardwareSerial & SerialB = Serial; // an alias, not a new instance

void setup() {
  SerialB.begin(115200);
  SerialB.print(0x33, HEX);
```

Note the ampersand.